# How to understand and view parsing of HTML-embedded JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I want to learn more about XSS, but I can't seem to find good resources on how HTML-embedded JavaScript, like the below code snippet, is parsed.

How can I view in the browser, how this code is parsed? I.e. how many rounds of parsing are performed, how each round transforms the input (e.g. decoding) etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="setTimeout(() => alert(1), 1000)">Click this!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

After HTML parsing is performed, that decodes HTML encoded entites, what does the program look like? Does HTML parsing also mess with the `onclick` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is fairly broad but seems to generally relate to how browsers render web pages.

Your browser requests the web document and begins interpreting it, reading line by line and building a *Object Oriented* representation of the **Document Object Model (DOM)**; the **DOM** interfaces between javascript logic and the html document to dynamically construct the application.

When the browser reaches your button it renders the element with the written attributes; upon parsing the onclick attribute, it sets a event listener to the **DOM** for the click event and the event listener invokes the defined function asynchronously with the set parameters when the event is detected.

Please update your question if you require clarification on something specific or not addressed.

Comment: @Shuzheng, has your question been answered? Does something else need clarification?